# Azure: Unable to merge automatically: Zero bytes ('\0') are not allowed. A zero byte has been found at position ***. Parameter name: ****

Tags: git, azure-devops

I was create a PR in azure devops, when it approved by reviewer this message appear

> Unable to merge automatically: Zero bytes ('\0') are not allowed. A zero byte has been found at position ***. Parameter name: ****

I don't know how to debug this error, i hope someone can explain what happen and how to debug this error

Thank you !

Comment: When you say "approved", do you mean the PR is trying to complete, and that error appears? Also, it's good that you pasted the error as text, but perhaps a screenshot would help too in this case. I can't picture in my mind at what point (or place on the screen) that this error would show up.